# Why do I need an extra screen click for hiding an element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to hide an element with the jQuery `.hide()` method.

When the active radio button is selected, an element should hide. The problem is when I select the active button nothing happens, but after that when I click anywhere on the screen the element gets hidden.

I have uploaded the code on jsfiddle, found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nvq873u5/5/).

Can anyone please help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?

Comment: I think you want to listen to the `change` DOM event, as opposed to `click`.

Comment: Code should be posted on Stack Overflow, not on jsfiddle.  See [this discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276325/should-we-discourage-links-to-jsfiddle-collaboration-sessions?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m24v6e3a/):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="content">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">

                <div class="form-group">

                <h5>Use standard Pricing.</h5>
                <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
              <label class="btn btn-secondary">
                <input type="radio" name="different_price" id="different_price_na" autocomplete="off"> Not Active
              </label>
              <label class="btn btn-secondary active">
                <input type="radio" name="different_price" id="different_price_a" autocomplete="off" checked=""> Active
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
            <hr>

            </div>
                </div>

            <div id="pricing_col" style="">
              <div class="row">


            <div class="col-lg-12">
                  <div class="form-group ">
                    <label for="id_orignal_price">Orignal Price</label>
                    <input type="number" name="orignal_price" class="form-control" id="id_orignal_price" step="0.01" required="">

                  </div>
                </div>

                  </div>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="id_discount">Discount</label>
                        <input type="number" name="discount" class="form-control" id="id_discount" step="0.01" required="">

                      </div>
                  </div>
                    <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                      <div class="form-group ">
                        <label for="id_shiping_price">Shipping Price</label>
                        <input type="number" name="shiping_price" class="form-control" id="id_shiping_price" step="0.01" required="">

                      </div>
                    </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="text-center">
                        <hr>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
                                        <h5>12<br><small>Orignal Price</small></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-4">
                                        <h5>2<br><small>Discount</small></h5>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <h5>24,6$<br><small>Final Price</small></h5>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
            </div>



              </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  var different_price = $("input[name='different_price']")


    $(document.body).on('change', different_price, function() {
      if($("[name='different_price']:checked").attr('id')=='different_price_a')
      {

$("#pricing_col").show("slow");
      }
      else {
        $("#pricing_col").hide("slow");
      }
    });



});
```

Comment: Thanks its is working, could you help me understand what's wrong with click ?

Comment: `click` triggers too early (before the checked value changes).

Comment: @PankajSharma What I did it to replace the ```click``` event by ```change``` event and to set the default (begin) state inside the html to ```Active``` insted of ```Not Active```. Then I saw that the buttons active in the oposite way then the should and I replaced the event of the ```show``` with the event of the ```hide```. For your question- The ```change``` event is better to this kind of states, because you care of the buttons only if the different button has been chosen, and not if the same button has been clicked twice.

Answer (score 2):

You end up needing to click the screen again after clicking the radio button because that is the only time the hide/show logic is ran.

As stated in the comments, use the [`change`](https://api.jquery.com/change/) event.

```
$(".btn-group input").change(function(){
  if($("[name='different_price']:checked").attr('id')=='different_price_a'){
    $("#pricing_col").hide("slow");
  }
  else {
    $("#pricing_col").show("slow");
  }
});
```

I made the same update to this version of the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nvq873u5/29/